# Keep same URL but contract changes in Spring Boot REST Open API 3?

Tags: spring, swagger, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I am using `Spring Boot and REST and Open API 3` implementation. In this example, `v1` Group has List implementation - all data will get in List, in `v2` Group has pagination implementation - all data will come in the form of pages.

For the consumer, we don't want to change endpoint url for them to be consume.

Endpoint which returns list.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/contacts", headers = {"Accept-version=v1"})
public ResponseEntity<List<Contact>> findAll() {
    List<Contact> contacts = contactService.findContactList();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(contacts, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Endpoint with Pagination

```
@GetMapping(value = "/contacts", headers = {"Accept-version=v2"})
public ResponseEntity<List<Contact>> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Contact> contactPages = contactService.findContactPageable(pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(contactPages, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I want V1 endpoint to be shown in `GroupedOpenApi` and v2 endpoint to be shown in the `GroupedOpenApi2`. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you put the two endpoints in different packaged and then use the Following GroupedOpenApi definition:

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi groupOpenApiV1() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .setGroup("v1")
            .packagesToScan("test.org.springdoc.api.v1")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi groupOpenApiV2() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .setGroup("v2")
            .packagesToScan("test.org.springdoc.api.v2")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: You're great ! Thanks for nice help, however I can't keep the same controller name, making different controller with same endpoint and different header version works fine.